# Android list view setOnItemClickListener works only if

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-wrap-content

I have an Android layout. I've set a listener like `list.setOnItemClickListener`. Everything seems to work fine.

In the line below:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

If I change `android:layout_height` from `wrap_content` to `fill_parent` it doesn't work anymore (the item from my list cannot be selected).

It works only if it's set to `wrap_content`. Why does this happen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        <ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/details"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:stretchColumns="1"
                         android:shrinkColumns="1"
                         android:paddingTop="4dip"
                    >
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/name" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/name" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/address" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/addr" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="Type:" />
                    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                     android:id="@+id/take_out"
                                     android:text="@string/takeout"
                                     android:checked="true"
                                />

                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                     android:id="@+id/sit_down"
                                     android:text="@string/sitdown"
                                />
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                     android:id="@+id/delivery"
                                     android:text="@string/delivery"
                                />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView android:text="@string/notes" />
                    <EditText android:id="@+id/notes" />
                </TableRow>

                <Button android:id="@+id/save"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/save"
                        />
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: it wont work as using `fill_parent` will try to fill all area inside `FrameLayout`, however there exist also a `ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"` included. Maybe a solution will be to but `ScrollView` in another `RelativeView` and place it below `ListView android:id="@+id/restaurants"`

Comment: Do a test: change listView background color to black and the ScrollView background color to red. Look what view your are working. It can be fill all space above listView.

Answer (score 0):

**`fill_parent`** (deprecated and renamed `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level 8 and higher)

> Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in. It's roughly equivalent of setting the dockstyle of a Windows Form Control to `Fill`.
>
> Setting a top level layout or control to fill_parent will force it to take up the whole screen.

**`wrap_content`**

> Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

There's some details in the Android code documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your ScrollView is taking up all avaliable space inside your ListView that can populate on your screen, basically covering it up.

You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.  --From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html